# How to read every n lines from txt file in C

Tags: c

I am reading from a text file and the file is in the format

```
value1: 5 
value2: 4 
value3: 3 
value4: 2 
value5: 1
```

and then it repeats.
I know how to grab the data I need from one line, but I've searched everywhere and looked through various books and resources and I can't figure out a way to read from every 10 lines instead of one line.

This is what I have so far and I am aware that it has a couple mistakes and I have extra variables and it is incomplete but I am able to compile and all it does is print the first value from the file. my printf is mostly just a test to see what I'm reading from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int line = 0;

int time = 0;
int switch0 = 0;
int switch1 = 0;
int switch2 = 0;
int switch3 = 0;
int pot = 0;
int temp = 0;
int light = 0;
FILE *infile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
FILE *outfile = fopen("matlab.csv", "w");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit(0);
}

fprintf(outfile, "Time,Switch0,Switch1,Switch2,Switch3,Potentiometer,Temperature,Light");
fscanf(infile, "time: %d\nswitch0: %d\nswitch1: %d\nswitch2: %d\nswitch3: %d\npotentiometer: %d\n temperature: %d\n light: %d\n",
    &time, &switch0, &switch1, &switch2, &switch3, &pot, &temp, &light) != EOF;



    printf("%d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n %d\n", time, switch0, switch1, switch2, switch3, pot, temp, light);

}
```

tl;dr how to read every 10 lines of text file and save into array
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read line by line, and increment a counter. When it gets to 10, process the line and set the counter back to 0.

Comment: Why `fscanf(infile, "time: %d\n",...` instead of `fscanf(infile, "value%*d: %d\n",...` ?

Comment: Reading into `&time[100]` results in undefined behavior. The valid indexes of the `time` array are 0 through 99.

Comment: chux, its just the way the txt file is written, i summarized the format. that part works as it is.

Comment: @user7033612 It looks like you've edited the question to include the answer, which may be confusing to future readers. If you need further help, you should make that clear; otherwise, you might want to roll back the edit so that your original question can help other people.

Answer (score 2):

> I know how to grab the data I need from one line

Well that's a good start. If you can read one line, you can read one line *n* times, right?

> I've searched everywhere and looked through various books and resources and I can't figure out a way to read from every 10 lines instead of one line.

It's just more of the same. You could, for example, write a function that reads exactly one line and returns the data. Then call that function the requisite number of times.

If you really want to read all the data from *n* lines at once, you can do that to. Instead of your code:

```
fscanf(infile, "time: %d\n", &time[100]);
```

you can make the format string more extensive:

```
fscanf(infile, "time: %d\nswitch1: %d\nswitch2: %d\npotentiometer: %d\n",
                &time, &switch1, &switch2, &potentiometer);
```

The `\n` is just another character to `fscanf()` -- you don't have to stop reading at the end of one line.

Be careful with this approach, though. It leaves you open to problems if you have a malformed file -- everything will break if one of the lines you expect happens to be missing or if one of the labels is misspelled. I think you'd be better off reading one line at a time, and reading both the label and the value, like:

```
fscanf(infile, "%s %d\n", &label, &value);
```

Then you can look at the string in `label` and figure out which line you're dealing with, and then store the `value` in the appropriate place. You'll be better able to detect and recover from errors.

Comment: I tried something like this and all my values are 0 except for the time value. I will edit the original post.